# How can I tell if passed in element is one or multiple elements?

Tags: class, mootools, element

I'm learning how to use Mootools' [Class](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class), and I am trying to figure out how to detect whether a passed in element is just a single element (for example, `$('foo')`), or an Elements instance (e.g. `$$('.class')`).

I attempted to use typeOf, but both examples return me the type "object".

I am aware that many Mootools functions can apply to both an Element instance and an Elements instance, but my class needs to know what it is receiving, or else it won't know to iterate through all passed in elements, for example.

Is there a way I can differentiate between the two?

Comment: really? `typeOf($$("a")); // elements`. also, they will typically have a .length property and array-like methods as well as many element methods that map to the array via an each. whereas a single element goes `typeOf(document.getElement("a")); // element`. I tend to go, `if (elsArray && elsArray.length) { ... }` though this may fail if you have a single element with a property of length on the object. fun check: `instanceOf($$("a"), Elements); // true` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `typeOf` function in mootools should be adequate, I would suggest you check your code to make sure the problem isn't somewhere else. That said, you can also check for the existence of the 'each' function, which is a part of the array prototype extended by mootools:

```
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>

<div id="myId"></div>

console.log(typeof $$('.myClass').each); // function
console.log(typeof $('myId').each); // undefined
```

However, the mootools function `typeOf` (docs: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Core/Core#Core:typeOf) should be giving you the best information. Be sure you aren't using javascript's built-in operator `typeof` (which I **did** use in the example above), but the moootools function `typeOf` as follows:

```
console.log(typeOf($$('.myClass'))); // elements
console.log(typeOf($('myId'))); // element
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/49DwN/

Also note, the `typeOf` return for a group of elements is "element**s**", where a single element is "element" - note the "s" there. Javascript's `typeof` operator would return "object" for both cases.

Comment: though mootools actually has typeOf and instanceOf, your logic can break. you should check the prototype implicitly and not just .each - eg. `<div each="foo" id="myid">i break js</div>`

Comment: `<div each="foo" id="myid">i break js</div>` - `typeof $('myId').each == 'string'` - does not break if you're testing for 'function'.`typeOf` is safe to use in the OP's example, the checking for `each` is a superfluous or alternate approach.

Comment: `console.log(typeOf($$('.a')));    // elements`... good god, I must've been using native typeOf, not realizing that Mootools has its own. Thanks to you both, @DimitarChristoff, @Chris

Comment: You kind of did it again in your comment :P Mootools function - `typeOf`, javascript operator - `typeof`. In older versions of mootools, the function was `$type` , I think that was a better name, it avoids confusion. A little `$type = typeOf` at the bottom of your moo.js file wouldn't be horrible idea...

Comment: it was deemed bad form (again) to use `$name` conventions about an year ago, i can't remember why - either way, mootools then shied away and renamed. i also think typeOf vs typeof can be confusing, though one is a function and one is an operator that can also act as a function...

Comment: Yeah, we're talking about "bad form" over in chat right now... I say pah!